# RealmSwift - Passing query as dynamic parameter fails

Tags: swift, swiftui, realm

I'm having an issue passing a query as a function parameter. Although the type of the query is the same as when used directly within the class, (and when I copy & paste the code, it works), it won't work – returns a basic strange error:

This is where I'm accessing the filter:

`Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to closure result type 'Query<Bool>'`.

```
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift

struct PostFeed: View {
    @ObservedResults(Post.self) private var posts
    
    init(where filter: ((Query<Post>) -> Query<Bool>)?) {
        self._posts = .init(Post.self, where: filter )
    }
}
```

And this is where I am passing the filter:

```
PostFeed { $0.posterId == id } // <-- Error appears here
```

...

If I remove the dynamic query parameter and enter the same query inside my view, it works. The query is otherwise valid if I structure it as:

```
init(_ id: String) {
    self.id = id
    self._posts = .init(Post.self, where: {$0.posterId == id} )
}
```

and

```
PostFeed(id)
```

I would like to make my example 1 work. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After asking a colleague to check the issue, we discovered the code was working as normal.

Command + K (Clean build folder) fixed the issue. Classic XCode move.

Answer (score 0):

What about changing the parameter type to

```
init(where filter: ((Query<Post>) -> Bool)?) {
    self._posts = .init(Post.self, where: filter)
}
```

Comment: This returns an error for not matching type